# Как осваивать тестирование?

Tags: java, тестирование, любой-язык, test-driven-development

В разработке я относительно недавно и несколько недель назад задумался над тем, что не тестирую свой код. Непорядок. Начал читать книгу Кент Бека про TDD. Уловил главную идею - "красный" - "зеленый" - "рефакторинг". Ну и что желательно двигаться маленькими шажками, чтобы проще было.
Начал кодить в таком стиле и понял, что порой просто захожу в тупик, не зная, что тестировать и как. Например, отправка почты, как тестировать? Отправлять себе письмо? По сути, я тестировал полностью весь класс, стараясь покрыть каждый метод хоть небольшим тестом, чтобы удостовериться, что он работает. Я задумался, возможно стоит не полностью покрывать код тестами, а только те части, где сложная логика.

Опытные разработчики, посоветуйте, как лучше осваивать тестирование, стоит ли дальше двигаться в направлении TDD или может нужно повременить, опыта поднабраться в тестировании. Что нужно тестировать и как? Возможно есть правила, которые вы выработали для себя.

Comment: Ну это же от обстоятельств зависит. Иногда тяп-ляп и в продакшен.

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос именно в методике тестирования, если без тяп-ляпов.

Comment: Ну как образец отличников производства - https://www.sqlite.org/testing.html  у них тесты объемом в несколько сот раз больше чем сам код

Comment: мы сейчас тестируем очень сложную систему. у нас тесты реализуют часть функционала самой системы. иначе никак. это везде так. 
советую еще code inspection и code duplicate натравить на код тестов и системы.

Comment: По поводу сложной системы. Когда, на ваш взгляд, имеет смысл применение тестов? Или стоит всегда ими покрывать код?

Comment: "Ну это же от обстоятельств зависит. Иногда тяп-ляп и в продакшен." Да все мы грешны но такой подход всегда сулит выявление багов на прод системе а не во время тестов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы все делаете правильно - нужно писать тесты с самого начала и стремится к большему % покрытию кода. То, что Вы не можете придумать, как и что протестировать с опытом пройдет, а в данный момент можно тестировать, как получается. Относительно того как тестировать методы/классы или реализуемую ими функциональность то могу предложить сначала определится с методологией тестирования для начала посмотрите на: [тестирования по стратегии белого ящика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) и [тестирования по стратегии чёрного ящика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

> Что нужно тестировать и как?

По моему мнению и опыту тестировать в первую очередь нужно всю «нетипичную» логику. То есть те специфичные вещи которые Вы пишите для данного приложения, а не то что данные из базы выгружаются верно (хотя это тоже нужно протестировать) или метод действительно открывает файл.

Я стараюсь в первую очередь тестировать самые важные куски кода которые в случае если будут изменены обязательно должны сигнализировать разработчику (не прохождением теста), что логика работы стала отлична от ожидаемой (тестом), что должно обязать разработчика актуализировать тест.

Относительно того как тестировать – для критически важных участков кода я применяю сразу несколько тестов: на функциональность (черный ящик) – подаю все возможные значения на вход и проверяю на соответствие выходного значения или выбрасывания исключения, или наличие/отсутствие побочного эффекта, и код с помощью критериев покрытия [MC/DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage).